# как сделать программу по высчитыванию проработанных часов на python

Tags: python

Есть таблица excel, в которой указано время прихода работников на свое рабочее место и время ухода. Как должна выглядеть программа, в которой должно быть написано имя работника, а также количество проработанных часов.

Comment: Мне кажется, это делается прямо в Excel при помощи только одной мышки.

Comment: @GrAnd вы не могли бы рассказать поподробнее?

Comment: =A2-A1 , где А1 время прихода, А2 время ухода.

Comment: @Эникейщик это понятно, просто есть одна проблема. С 13:00 до 14:00 обед, и его нужно вычесть. Но если человек ушёл до обеда или пришёл после то вычитать его не нужно

Comment: Ещё что есть? Потом выяснится, что если суббота, то надо умножать на 1,5, а если воскресенье, то на 2,7. Сразу в вопросе нельзя все условия указать?

Comment: Сделайте 2 колонки | был до обеда | был после | и в итоге суммируйте эти значения, либо оставьте как предлагали выше но добавьте поле корректировка и заполняйте там данные вручную. Можно нагородить вокруг этого программу конечно но зачем переписывать excel? так если для тренировки только.

Comment: @Эникейщик извиняюсь, повторюсь я абсолютный новичок. И по моему профилю вы можете заметить, что это лишь первый мой вопрос.

Comment: @Kers спасибо большое)

Comment: @АндрейКозлов Добавил ответ как прямо в Excel можно посчитать время без учёта обеденного перерыва.

Comment: @GrAnd огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Дано:

[image: Дано]

Выделяем нужную для результата ячейку и в ней же пишем "=". Далее нужно будет выделить ячейку В2(синяя), над которой мы будем совершать действие(в данном случае вычитание из времени ухода время прихода). При выделении её курсором её номер автоматически запишется в нашу ячейку. Далее набираем "-" и выделяем вторую ячейку А2(красная). Больше никаких операторов нам не нужно, потому нажимаем enter:

[image: формула]

Если протянуть за правый нижний угол ячейку вниз, то формула применится на всю выделенную Вами область:

[image: итог]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но есть одна проблема. С 13:00 до 14:00 обед, и его нужно вычесть. Но если человек ушёл до обеда или пришёл после то вычитать его не нужно

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно вычесть из учтённого времени обеденный перерыв, то проще всего будет в отдельных столбцах посчитать время до обеда и после обеда, а потом эти времена сложить.

[image: -]

Времена считаются по формулам:

```
ДоОбеда    = МАКС(0, МИН(ВремяПрихода, ВремяНачалаОбеда) - ВремяПрихода)
ПослеОбеда = МАКС(0, ВремяУхода - МАКС(ВемяПрихода, ВремяОкончанияОбеда))
```

[image: -]
[image: -]
[image: -]